# Adding dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary, collections

i'm trying to build a function

```
def adding_3dict(d1,d2,d3)
```

The function gets 3 dictionaries d1,d2,d3,
create from them one dictionary D 
such that if a key is found in more than one dictionary from d1,d2,d3,
its value in D will be a tuple with all its values in all dictionaries.
The rest of the pairs from d1,d2,d3, are copied as they are to D .
The function returns the new dictionary D.

Example:

```
d1={1:'a',3:'d',5:'e'}
d2={1:'b',3:(11,22),7:'f',4:'q'}
d3={2:'c',3:'x',4:'t',8:'g'}
```

The output dictionary is:

```
d =  {1: ('a', 'b'), 2: 'c', 3: ('d', (11, 22), 'x'), 4: ('q', 't'), 5: 'e', 7: 'f', 8: 'g'}
```

i tried:

```
import collections

d1={}
d2={}
d3={}
def adding_3dict(d1,d2,d3):
    d={}
    d=dict(d1.items() + d2.items()+ d3.items() )

    return d
```

i tried it and my output is:

```
>>> 
>>> adding_3dict( {1:'a',3:'d',5:'e'}, {1:'b',3:(11,22),7:'f',4:'q'} , {2:'c',3:'x',4:'t',8:'g'} )
{1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'x', 4: 't', 5: 'e', 7: 'f', 8: 'g'} #the output
>>>
```

how can i change the output from

```
{1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'x', 4: 't', 5: 'e', 7: 'f', 8: 'g'}
```

to

```
{1: ('a', 'b'), 2: 'c', 3: ('d', (11, 22), 'x'), 4: ('q', 't'), 5: 'e', 7: 'f', 8: 'g'}
```

Comment: Are tuples needed here? Could you use lists instead? Tuples are immutable and make things more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which will accept an arbitrary number of dictionaries:

```
from itertools import chain

def custom_dictmerge(*args):
    result = {}
    keys = set(chain(*(d.keys() for d in args)))
    for k in keys:
        result[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in args if k in d)
        if len(result[k]) == 1:
            result[k] = result[k][0]
    return result
```

Call `custom_dictmerge(d1, d2, d3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `defaultdict` from `collections` allows you to append all the values to a list. So you only have to parse the keys of each dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mergedict(list_of_dicts):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for di in list_of_dicts:
        for k, v in di.items():
            d[k].append(v)
    return d
```

If you really need tuples and single values, then you can always convert the list to whatever type you wish.

```
def convert_to_tuples(d):
    """ converts values inplace """
    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(v) > 1:
            d[k] = tuple(v)
        else:
            d[k] = v[0]
    return d
```